# Rabbitmq - queues state shows as 'running' , GUI shows status as IDLE

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I was playing around the rabbitmq HTTP API and came across a weird scenario. When I look at my queues through the web interface, the status of both of them shows as IDLE. [image: queue status IDLE].

However when I use the HTTP API, the return for both the queue shows as 'running'. The code im using is below:

```
import requests
import json

uri = 'http://localhost:15672/api/queues'

r = requests.get(uri, auth=("guest","guest"))

parsed = json.loads(r.content)
#print json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
for i in parsed:
    print '{:<20} : {}'.format(i.get('name'), i.get('state'))
```

Output:

```
test queue           : running
test2                : running
```

Can someone explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: Perhaps poke around at the javascript and see what it is doing with the output from the api?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the Management_console source code here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/blob/master/priv/www/js/formatters.js#L479

```
function fmt_object_state(obj) {
    if (obj.state == undefined) return '';

    var colour = 'green';
    var text = obj.state;
    var explanation;

    if (obj.idle_since !== undefined) {
        colour = 'grey';
        explanation = 'Idle since ' + obj.idle_since;
        text = 'idle';
    }
```

The console shows "idle" if the field `idle_since` is not null.

If there is "traffic" in your queue you will have a json like that:

```
      "policy":"",
      "exclusive_consumer_tag":"",
      "consumers":0,
      "consumer_utilisation":"",
      "memory":176456,
      "recoverable_slaves":"",
      "state":"running",
```

if the queue is in idle (without traffic) you will have a json like that:

```
      "idle_since":"2015-06-25 10:15:07",
      "consumer_utilisation":"",
      "policy":"",
      "exclusive_consumer_tag":"",
      "consumers":0,
      "recoverable_slaves":"",
      "state":"running",
```

As you can see the field `"idle_since"` is not null.

In both cases the queue is always in `running` state.

In conclusion it is just a web-view formatting.

Comment: Yes I did the same thing. Just looked at the `json` for `idle_since`. If its there, then the queue is marked as `IDLE` , otherwise its `RUNNING`